# Where is the google-chrome instance?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to open google-chrome,but can't:

```
debian@debian:~$ which  google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
debian@debian:~$ google-chrome
[6605:6605:0713/170233.016537:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(1004)] Failed to create socket directory.
[6605:6605:0713/170233.016697:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1278)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

I can't find where the instance is ?

```
debian@debian:~$ ps aux |grep  google
debian      6648  0.0  0.0  12684   820 pts/0    S+   17:02   0:00 grep google
debian@debian:~$ ps aux |grep  chrome
debian      6651  0.0  0.0  12684   876 pts/0    S+   17:02   0:00 grep chrome
```

Should i free up space?

```
 df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      191293324 73507036 107999460  41% /
```

Comment: You don't need to free up space : Only 41% of the disk is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error basically means that chromium can't create its "ProcessSingleton" socket.

Check if the `/tmp` is set as `chmod 1777`.
These special permission are so that all users can write to it,
but only the owners have access to their objects within.

Consider cleaning out `/tmp` of anything that looks related to
chrome or chromium. (Have you also installed chromium?)

`/tmp` night also be full, and in that case clean up some space.

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying that an instance is running.

It's saying that inability to acquire a lock would make it possible to run multiple instances, which in turn would lead to profile corruption. Therefore it's refusing to start.

Answer (score 0):

## You most likely need to free up space on `/`

*(unless you have your partitions set up some other way, then you'll need to run `df -h` and clear up space in the partition containing `/usr/bin`)*

---

Chrome is outputting to you:

> Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.

Meaning that it is *not allowing* an instance of Chrome to run, therefore of course you can't find the process using `ps aux` because it doesn't exist.

While I don't use Chrome, I've had a similar error (not being able to create a socket directory) which was caused by my root partition (`/`) running out of storage space. Clearing up some space there should allow Chrome to start running properly, and then you can find it in `ps aux`.

It's likely that you'll start experiencing problems on other programs without doing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
debian@debian:~$ ls  /tmp
debian@debian:~$ ls -al /tmp
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 16384 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root  4096 Jul 13 18:21 ..
debian@debian:~$ sudo umount  /tmp
```

Now i can start  chrome browser .

Comment: You should investigate why something was mounted on /tmp, what mounted it and if that's intended behavior.